# Downloading thumbnail to UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsoperationqueue

I have a `UITableView` that populates its cells with thumbnail images. In my case, the thumbnails are downloaded from a server. My code is as follows:

```
if (![self thumbnailExists])
{
    self.thumbnailImageView.image = nil;
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:
    ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.thumbnailURL]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:
         ^{
             SubmenuScrollViewTableViewCell *submenuScrollViewTableViewCell = (SubmenuScrollViewTableViewCell*)[(UITableView*)self.superview cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPath];
             [submenuScrollViewTableViewCell.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
             submenuScrollViewTableViewCell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
         }];
    }];

    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    [self.operationQueues setObject:operation forKey:[self title]];
}
```

This code is based on the great WWDC2012 presentation: "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS". The main difference between my code and the code in the presentation is I'm populating my cells with data that is retrieved from the web.

It works well for the most part, but the problem I'm having is if I scroll really fast, then one of the cells might show up with the wrong thumbnail (usually I noticed said cell would be a multiple of the cell from which the thumbnail belongs to). I should mention this code is being executed in the `layoutSubviews` method of an overridden `UITableViewCell`.

Can anyone spot any flaws in this code?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @AdamG - yeah I did see below, thanks for the help gave you a point up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the fact that the above code was in the layoutSubviews method of a subclassed UITableViewCell I created. When I moved it back in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, the problem was eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is breaking is because of this line of code:

```
 SubmenuScrollViewTableViewCell *submenuScrollViewTableViewCell = (SubmenuScrollViewTableViewCell*)[(UITableView*)self.superview cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPath];
```

You are grabbing the cell at the index path when this is called and placing it in whatever cell is at this index path when the cell is reused.  This puts a different image in a different cell when the view moves very fast and perhaps the response from the server comes in at a different time.

Make sure you cancel the operation in prepareForReuse and clear out the cell image so that it does not place the image in the wrong cell, or an image does not get re-used.

Also, it is generally bad practice to call the tableView from the cell itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response Adam. I've seen that line of code recommended in numerous places because the idea is, if the cell has already been rolled off the screen, it will return nil. I do see your point though on not calling the tableview from the cell itself. Is it possible this problem stems from having the code in the UITableViewCell rather then in the UITableView itself?

Comment: I think that could be the issue.  I was thinking that since the cells is being re-used the reference to self.indexPath would bring back a non-nil response.  That also explains why it is likely a multiple of the cell.  If this is the issue, a solution might be to store the indexPath in the block right when the block is called before the asynchronous call back and use the stored indexPath to grab the cell.

Comment: try setting your imageview's image property to nil after the cell has been dequeued in cellForRowAtIndexPath to avoid having one image in multiple cells.